# thref from ntheorem not working with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, ntheorem

I want to use the extended reference features from ntheorem, but they seem to be not working with hyperref, even with the parameter hyperref for ntheorem.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[thref,hyperref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}\label{sec}[Testsection]

Cite with thref: \thref{sec}

\end{document}
```

Here the optional parameter [Testsection] ist not recognised as a parameter but instead printed out.
If I remove hyperref everything is working as intended.

Comment: What does referencing a section have to do with `\thref`?

Comment: Same applies to Theorems, took just the simplest Example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that the option `thref` to `ntheorem` does a long series of hacks that are difficult to cope with when `hyperref` is used.

You can use `cleveref` that's much more robust.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\crefformat{Testsection}{#2Test section~#1#3}{}
\crefformat{Specialtheorem}{#2Special theorem~#1#3}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}\label[Testsection]{sec}

\begin{theorem}\label[Specialtheorem]{thm}
Theorem statement
\end{theorem}

Cite with cref: \cref{sec} and \cref{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thats exectaly what i need. Sad that ntheorem doesn't work as it should, but at least there're pleanty other ways of doing so.

Answer (score 2):

It does work with theorems, ntheorem has implemented there a (rather convulated) way to get the data from an external file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}


\usepackage[hyperref,thref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}

\begin{document}

\begin{prop}[Hallo]\label{theo}
abc
\end{prop}

Cite with thref: \thref{theo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but thats not what I mean, in your Example it should be possible to write \label{theo}[special Prop]  and then \thref(theo) should write "special Prop 1" , but instead it writes [special Prop] out in the Prop and \thref(theo) still gives "Proposition 1". Thats what normaly is working and an official Feature of ntheorem, but doesnt work with hyperref included.

Comment: no that won't work. And I also think that the ntheorem code is quite bad here. Redefining \label and \newlabel in such an incompatible way, when they are so many other packages and code around which want to handle labels and references is bound to break somewhere.

Comment: Ok i guess i have to live with it and use another Package for that. Thank you very much.