# Is ntheorem[thref] truly incompatible with hyperref?

Tags: hyperref, package-options, ntheorem, abntex2

I was using the texlive version from Ubuntu's repos, but then started needing some features from the latest versions of some packages, so I replaced the repos' texlive with a new system from https://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html

Then, some documents that compiled perfectly started giving this error message
(let's call it a "bug"):

`ERROR: Paragraph ended before \Hy@setref@link was complete.`

(After a mini heart attack)
I managed to isolate the problem to this (sort-of-MWE):

```
\documentclass{abntex2}  % subclass of memoir that loads hyperref
% using any other class is not an option

\usepackage[
  backend = biber,
  %style = abnt, % this option doesn't matter for the bug
]{biblatex}

\usepackage[thref]{ntheorem}


\begin{document}
\section{Lorem ipsum}\label{loremipsum}

Reference to section~\ref{loremipsum}.
Some other text.

\end{document}
```

Some comments:

- Some versions:
  `ntheorem: 1.33 2011/08/15`,
  `abntex2: 1.9.7 2018/11/24`,
  `hyperref: 7.00 2022/06/20`.
- Changing the class from `abntex2` to `memoir` (its base class) dispels the bug;
- Omitting the `thref` option of `ntheorem` dispels the bug, but you must also erase the files the compilation generates, and then recompile;
- Loading `amsmath` (with or without the `amsmath` option to `ntheorem`) has no effect on the bug;
- Using the `hyperref` option in `ntheorem` has no effect also.

It seems I didn't really need the `thref` functionality described in the package's docs, so for now I'll just remove it,
but I'd appreciate if someone savvier could tell what went wrong, whether there's a way to fix it, etc.

(Although [`ntheorem[thref]` and `hyperref` seem known not to get along very well](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/609523),
they were behaving just fine with the slightly outdated versions from the Ubuntu repos,
behave fine with the `memoir` class,
and `ntheorem` should (theoretically=according to its docs) work with `hyperref`, as long as you give it the proper loading option,
so I think there's some value in pointing out this "bug").

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### unchanged things

The `thref` option of `ntheorem` is and was always incompatible with `hyperref`.

*Without* hyperref a label like
`\label{theo}[additional text]` will write

```
\newlabel{theo}{{1}{1}}[additional text]
```

to the aux file, and a `\thref` can then retrieve the `additional text`.

[image]

If `hyperref` is loaded this no longer works. `ntheorem` contains here a bit of repair code to retrieve at least a "keyword", but the optional argument of `\label` can no longer be used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[thref,hyperref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}

\begin{prop}[Hallo]\label{theo}[additional text]
abc
\end{prop}

Cite with thref: \thref{theo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### what is new

Since a few months `hyperref` no longer delays the loading of `nameref` to `\begin{document}` but loads it directly. For your example that means that `hyperref` and `nameref` are both loaded *before*  `ntheorem` and so no longer overwrite its `\label` definition to repair at least in part the damage the `thref` option does.

So either don't use this option, or force the loading of `ntheorem` before `hyperref`:

```
\AddToHook{package/hyperref/before}{\RequirePackage[thref,hyperref]{ntheorem}}
\documentclass ...
```

### what is new 2023

Since the LaTeX release 2023-06-01, the LaTeX kernel itself defines `\label` as needed for links. `hyperref` therefore no longer redefines it later.

Now the `thref` option of ntheorem really harms, as it redefine `\label` in way that is not usable with LaTeX and `hyperref`. The option should not be used anymore!