# Conflict of pdfx (hyperref), ntheorem, and cleveref

Tags: hyperref, cleveref, ntheorem, pdfx, option-clash

Compiling the MWE

```
\documentclass{book} 

\usepackage[x-1a1]{pdfx}% also loads hyperref
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[amsmath,amsthm,thref,thmmarks]{ntheorem}    
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}\label{ch:foo}

\begin{theorem}[bar's theorem]\label{thm:bar}
bar.
\begin{align}
    1   &=1     \label{eq}
\end{align}
\end{theorem}

\Cref{ch:foo,thm:bar,eq} are important.

\end{document}
```

twice with `pdfTeX` or `LuaHBTeX` on `TeX Live 2023` leads to the the error

> ./packageClashMWE.tex:21: Argument of @fifthoffive has an extra
> }.
>
> <inserted text>
>
> \par
>
> l.21 \Cref{sec: fooSection,theo,eq} are important.

This was not an issue with the `hyperref` version shipped in the early version of `TeX Live 2022`.

The problem does not occur if either

1. `pdfx` (which relies on `hyperref`) and `hyperref`, or
2. all instances of `cleveref`, or
3. all instances of `nteorem`

are removed. Of course, this is an unwanted limitation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option `thref` of `ntheorem` is not necessary as you may use the tools provided by `cleveref` instead of `\thref`. The following simple change runs without the error.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[x-1a1]{pdfx}% also loads hyperref
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[amsmath,amsthm,thmmarks]{ntheorem}% observe the small change    
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{section foo}\label{sec: fooSection}

\begin{theorem}[foo thoerem]\label{theo}
bar.
\begin{align}
    1   &=1     \label{eq}
\end{align}
\end{theorem}

\Cref{sec: fooSection,theo,eq} are important.

\end{document}
```

Comment: yes you shouldn't use this thref option, it is (and was) broken with hyperref, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/654404/2388.

Comment: Thank you for the insight in your link. I have not found anything in the hyperref manual, the cleveref manual does not mention a problem with the thref option, and the ntheorem manual writes vaguely about "some bugfixes" in 3.4.