# Springer svmult and hyperref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, sv-classes

For many years I have used `svmult` together with `hyperref` without any problems.

Recently (June 2023) I received the warning

> Package hyperref Warning: Suppressing link with empty target on input line...

with the normal crossref method (`\label{x}`, `\ref{x}`).

Ignoring the warnings results in a PDF document which still shows the correct references, but these references are now static, not dynamic links.

In contrast, the `\cite` commands (`biber`, `biblatex`) work as expected (dynamic links to the bibliography).

To narrow down the problem, I re-downloaded the latest package from https://www.springer.com/us/authors-editors/book-authors-editors/your-publication-journey/manuscript-preparation#c3324 (contributed books). The current version of `svmult.cls` is `5.9 (08-Sep-21)`. I use TeX Live (updated more or less daily) and LuaLaTeX (`LuaHBTeX, version 1.17.0 (TeX Live 2023)`) as engine. The sample files that come with the Springer Contributed Books package show the same warning:

> Package hyperref Warning: Suppressing link with empty target on input line...

when adding `\usepackage{hyperref}`. Without `hyperref` there are no warnings, but also no dynamic links.

Comment: well svmult loads ntheorem with the thref option and this is a problem, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/654404/2388. Reinstate the label definition like this https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/284#issuecomment-1588022830. And notify the class maintainer, the thref option should really not be used anymore.